# Project Reference Problem, Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, reference, project-reference

I have a solution that has one class library project, and the others are WPF applications.   I have added class library's reference the but, but both of them cannot use its classes.

So, what is the problem?

NOTE: sorry for tags, it's safari's problem.

Comment: have you tried to use reflector to check your library assembly to see everything is right?

Comment: @Kaan: What do you mean by "cannot use its classes"? Did you get compiler errors?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting compiler error: "The type or namespace name 'Core' does not exist in the namespace 'lt' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Comment: I realized that when I click "Clean Solution" button then it doesn't give an error but after I pressed Build it start to give me the errors. 

There is the error: http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/4823/errornf.png

Comment: found that if I add ADO.NET Entity Data Model to the class library, it starts to give me error. It contunies, although I removed it from class library.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the problem. One of my references in class library has caused it, and I have removed it. Now I can built the solution without errors.

Thanks for your comments..

Comment: Im having a similar problem, can you elaborate further on what the fix and issue was?

Answer (score 79):

Make sure that all your projects target same Framework.
It may be a case that your library class project targets full .Net Framework 4.0 while your wpf projects target .Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile.

To do that go to project properties of each project in a solution and check Application | Target Framework property. Alternatively you can download [VSCommands 2010](http://vscommands.com/download) extension and see all properties in one place via Solution Properties window.

Comment: Do you mean that they are ALL '.NET Framework 4.0' and none of them is '.NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile' ?

Comment: No, the class lib. Is .net 4 and the others .net 4 client profile.

Comment: Dude! +1 It is weird my project built once then not. It drove me mad. It seems my windows service decided be "Client Profile" and all the others were normal .NET4; Thanks man!

Comment: 4.5.1 vs 4.5. Yah, this one got me too.

Comment: Solved it for me. Too bad it wasn't the answer. That would've been pretty.

Answer (score 2):

Things to check:

- The class library classes are public
- You have an appropriate `using` directive in your calling code:

  ```
  using MyCompany.ClassLibrary;
  ```

If that doesn't help, please post what happens when you *try* to use the classes from the library.

Comment: All of them are public and I'm already defined using statement. I realized that, if I remove and then add reference it is ok until I hit the Build button. Then errors comes again. I have created another solution and moved codes by cop and paste (not direclty copy file) again problem continues. I think I have a problem with VS but I have also tried it with another computer that has same version of VS

Comment: Have the exact same problem here. I only want to add that when I first add the project to the reference and start typing in the using directive, visual studio even finds that project for me (with its IntelliSense thing). I then clean, and re-build, and then it can't find the type or namespace. Same as Kaan describes.

Comment: @Ilia. Where is the class library?

Comment: @JonSkeet; it was added under "References" to the current project; all of its classes had the correct namespace, too... The answer below regarding the project framework solved this problem for me. Thanks =)

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem, but the solution was different...

We work in team and one of the developers (called dev1) installed the .NET 4.5 (the others has only the .NET 4.0). After dev1 made some changes in the solution the others got the problem, and colud't build. The project referrences didn't work (but if they used it like a dll it worked)...
So we install the .NET 4.5 for everybody and it resolved the prolem.

Moha